# Python Selenium web scraping path

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image]

How do I convert the above to selenium xpath?

I tried:

```
"//ul[@id = 'productsCatalog AND @class = 'b-catalogList_wrapper clearfix']"
```

but it gives an error

Comment: 1- This is already `xpath` 2- What is the error? 3- Post html as text, not image 4- You have an ID, why do you use `xpath` in the first place?

Comment: Please do not post code, error messages, data as a picture, post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the element is a *dynamic* element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.b-catalogList_wrapper.clearfix#productsCatalog")))
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class = 'b-catalogList_wrapper clearfix' and @id ='productsCatalog']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```